# Blocking DNS requests domain names containing the word "foo" with scapy

Tags: scapy

How to block DNS requests by domain names that contains the word "foo" in scapy. For example block all this domains: foo.com, foobar.com, barfooqux.com

Comment: What do you mean "block"?

Comment: redirect to nowhere

Comment: That's not possible with Scapy. Check out nfqueue